# Python pandas two table match to find latest date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, lookup

I want to do some matching in pandas like Vlookup in Excel. According to some conditions in Table1, find the latest date in Table2:

Table 1:

```
Name  Threshold1   Threshold2
A     9            8
B     14           13
```

Table 2:

```
Date   Name   Value   
1/1    A      10
1/2    A      9
1/3    A      9
1/4    A      8
1/5    A      8
1/1    B      15
1/2    B      14
1/3    B      14
1/4    B      13
1/5    B      13
```

The desired table is like:

```
Name  Threshold1   Threshold1_Date   Threshold2   Threshold2_Date
A     9            1/3               8            1/5
B     14           1/3               13           1/5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Table1 and 2 are pandas dataframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code

```
# assuming dataframe is already sorted on `date`
# drop the duplicates per Name and Value keeping the max date
cols = ['Name', 'Value']
s = df2.drop_duplicates(cols, keep='last').set_index(cols)['Date']

# for each threshold column use multindex.map to substitute 
# values from df2 based on matching Name and Threshold value
for c in df1.filter(like='Threshold'):
    df1[c + '_date'] = df1.set_index(['Name', c]).index.map(s)
```

#### Result

```
  Name  Threshold1  Threshold2 Threshold1_date Threshold2_date
0    A           9           8             1/3             1/5
1    B          14          13             1/3             1/5
```

Comment: Great solution.  I am too fancy. :)

Comment: Thanks Scott.. BTW why deleted the solution..it looks cool to me :-)

Comment: Thanks Shubham. BTW I didn't get a chance to read Scott's solution >_<

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
(df_out := df1.melt('Name', value_name='Value')\
   .merge(df2, on=['Name', 'Value'])\
   .sort_values('Date')\
   .drop_duplicates(['Name', 'variable'], keep='last')\
   .set_index(['Name', 'variable'])\
   .unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1))\
.set_axis(df_out.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Name Date_Threshold1  Value_Threshold1 Date_Threshold2  Value_Threshold2
0    A             1/3                 9             1/5                 8
1    B             1/3                14             1/5                13
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
latestDtByNameVal = df2.groupby(['Name','Value']).last()
resCols = (y for x in df1.columns if x != 'Name' for y in [x, f'{x}_Date'])
res = df1.assign(**( df1
    .set_index('Name')
    .pipe(lambda d:
        {f'{col}_Date': d[[col]]
            .rename(columns={col:'Value'})
            .set_index('Value', append=True)
            .pipe(lambda d2: latestDtByNameVal.Date[d2.index].to_numpy()) 
        for col in d.columns}) ))[resCols]
```

Explanation:

- Use `groupby().last()` to get `latestDtByNameVal`, which is the latest date in df2 indexed by unique `Name, Value` pair
- Prepare the result column order in a generator `resCols` as `Threshold1, Threshold1_Date, ...` as shown in the question
- To grow the columns of df1 to include the threshold date results as columns with labels ending in `_Date`, pass `assign()` a dict mapping `<threshColName>_Date` to the `Date` row values in `latestDtByNameVal` at corresponding `Name, Value` pair indices
- Put the columns in the desired order using `resCols`.

Output:

```
  Name  Threshold1 Threshold1_Date  Threshold2 Threshold2_Date
0    A           9             1/3           8             1/5
1    B          14             1/3          13             1/5
```